# Why does my generator function always return the same value?

Tags: python, list, generator, pascals-triangle

I want to build a generator for Bernoulli's triangle, the number `i` in the `j` line in the triangle is the partial sum of the first `i` numbers in pascal's triangle in line `j`.

the triangle would look like this :

[image]

which would be represented in python by lists :

```
[[1], [1,2], [1,3,4], [1,4,7,8]
```

My generator function returns `[1]` as the first output, which is correct, but then it returns `[]` all the time!

That's my code:

```
def next_row(row):
    n = len(row)
    new_row = [row[0]] + [row[i] + row[i+1] for i in range(n - 1)] + [row[-1]]
    return new_row


def generate_pascal():
    row =[1]
    while True:
        yield row
        row=next_row(row)


def generate_bernoulli():

    row=next(generate_pascal())
    n=len(row)
    while True:
        yield row
        row=[row[0]+sum(row[0:i]) for i in range(n-1)]
```

Comment: What do you mean by all the time and what exactly you want?

Comment: You never update `n` in `generate_bernoulli`.

Comment: You also only call `generate_pascal` once. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The `pascal` tag is for the Pascal language, not Pascal's triangle. Please read tag excerpts before using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you only called `next` once, rather than calling it every iteration. Secondly, you never updated row in each iteration. In addition, your partial sum and `yield` were interchanged. I fixed these by putting the call to `next` inside the while loop, and initializing the `pascal` generator outside it. Finally, your sum was a little off; I fixed this as well. The correct code is below:

```
def generate_bernoulli():
    pascal = generate_pascal()
    while True:
        row=next(pascal)
        n=len(row)
        row=[sum(row[0:i+1]) for i in range(n)]
        yield row
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute partial sums of the rows of Pascal's triangle. Here's how I'd write the code.

```
def partial_sums(xs):
    s = 0
    for x in xs:
        s += x
        yield s

def generate_bernoulli():
    for row in generate_pascal():
        yield list(partial_sums(row))
```